# Workflow for using precompiled ember/handlebars templates

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember.js-view

So, I've got my Ember views set up to use external template files (.handlebars). The general mechanism is like so. I'm using requirejs module format:

```
define([
    "ember",
    "text!templates/drawer-menu.handlebars"
], 
function(Ember, drawerMenu) {
    var DrawerMenu = Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(drawerMenu),
    });

    return DrawerMenu;
});
```

Now, I've set up my project so I can use [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) for things like bundle, uglify, minify and pack all the css & js files.

I'd also like to precompile my templates. So I set up [grunt-ember-templates](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates) which nicely packs all my templates into one js file. The generated js file looks like this:

```
define(["ember"], function(Ember){
    Ember.TEMPLATES["drawer-menu"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(
        function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
           ....
           return buffer;
        });
);
```

I undestand, I should now be using `Ember.TEMPLATES["drawer-menu"]` instead of `Ember.Handlebars.compile(drawerMenu)` whenever I need the template data.

My question is how should I be setting up the development workflow? I mean

1. Should I change my code to always use the precompiled templates, in
   which case I'll always have to precompile in my development
   environment also.
2. If I don't do the above, then every time I build for production, I
   have to manually edit all view files to use precompiled templates. Something error prone.

Is there a mechanism to set this up automatically?

Answer (score 0):

i'd switch to lazy loading templates and always precompiling.  They get compiled client side and it isn't like they are any less useful for debugging client side.

```
var DrawerMenu = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'drawer-menu',
});
```

Comment: If you're precompiling, do they still compile on client side? In this example, is the "drawer-menu" template is resolved from `Ember.TEMPLATES` or from your templates folder?

Comment: I use "grunt watch" for template compiler task. It's saves a lot of time.